# How do I make a method out of this console write-line mess?

Tags: c#, logging

```
class WriteLine
{
    public static void Red(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }

    public static void Cyan(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;

        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }


    public static void Yellow (string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }


    public static void Purple(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;

        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }


    public static void White(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }


    public static void Black(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }

    public static void Green(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }

}
class Write
{
    public static void Red(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

        Console.Write(input);
    }

    public static void Cyan(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;

        Console.Write(input);
    }


    public static void Yellow(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

        Console.Write(input);
    }


    public static void Purple(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;

        Console.Write(input);
    }


    public static void White(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        Console.Write(input);
    }


    public static void Black(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

        Console.Write(input);
    }

    public static void Green(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        Console.Write(input);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this and make it more compact, like into a method, I was thinking something so that I could use WriteLine.Red("test"); and it would print red text. New to C# any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "I was thinking something so that I could use WriteLine.Red("test"); and it would print red text" Your code looks like it already does it in that way. So what is the problem?

Comment: @TimSchmelter
There isnt a problem, was just wondering if I could somehow simplify it, because the code just looks like a mess for such a small task

Comment: provided an answer, note that i have modified it after you have accepted it. In this case its easier to provide two methods instead of the WriteMode enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will not require changes to your existing code using the writers, but makes the code a bit better:

```
class WriteLine
{
    public static void InNewLine(ConsoleColor color, string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = color;

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public static void Red(string s) => InNewLine(ConsoleColor.Red, s);
    public static void Cyan(string s) => InNewLine(ConsoleColor.Cyan, s);
    public static void Yellow (string s) => InNewLine(ConsoleColor.Yellow, s);
    public static void Purple(string s) => InNewLine(ConsoleColor.Magenta, s);
    public static void White(string s) => InNewLine(ConsoleColor.White, s);
    public static void Black(string s) => InNewLine(ConsoleColor.Black, s);
    public static void Green(string s) => InNewLine(ConsoleColor.Green, s);
}

// Similar for `Write`
```

BTW. The pattern of having a method that takes all options and then "shortcut" methods is used by [ILogger Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). It has `Log(ILogger, LogLevel, String, Object[])`, where you specify log level there also are "shortcut" methods:

- `LogCritical(ILogger, String, Object[])`
- `LogDebug(ILogger, String, Object[])`.
- ...

BTW2. It may be polite to restore the previous color after writing:

```
public static void InNewLine(ConsoleColor color, string s)
{
   Console.WriteLine();

   var c = Console.ForegroundColor;
   Console.ForegroundColor = color;

   Console.WriteLine(s);
   Console.ForegroundColor = c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this class for all your use cases:

```
public class ConsoleLineWriter
{
    public void WriteLine(ConsoleColor color, string text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    public void Write(ConsoleColor color, string text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.Write(text);
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var writer = new ConsoleLineWriter();
    writer.WriteLine(ConsoleColor.DarkBlue, "Foo");
    writer.WriteLine(ConsoleColor.Green, "Bah");
    writer.Write(ConsoleColor.Red, "SameLine1");
    writer.Write(ConsoleColor.Cyan, "SameLine2");
    writer.Write(ConsoleColor.White, null); // back to default
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple, I love it!